# IE screen flickers while scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

IE8 screen flickers when I try to scroll down. It works fine in Mozila and Chrome.
Only with IE it flickers.
My JSP structure.

```
<body>
    <div id="pContainer">
        <div id="gContainer" class="gFix">
            <table...>
                <tr class="header">
                    <td....>
                        ...
                    </td>
                </tr> 
                <tr class="bContent"..>
                    <td>
                    ...
                <tr>
                    ...
                </tr>
                ...
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wContent">
        <table id="container"...>
        ...
        </table>
        <div id="lghtbtn"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**css**

```
html, body {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Verdana, "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
}

#pContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: static;
}

#gContainer {
    width: 1002px;
    float: inherit;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: inherit;
    max-width: 1024px;
}

.container {
    height:80px;
    overflow:scroll;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
}

#bContent {
    top: 111px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 97%;
    clear: both;
    float: inherit;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    position: inherit;
    min-height: 481px;
    /*background-color: #efefef;*/
}
```

pContainer is the complete page. gContainer is the header, body part which contains body content which has got fields grids etc., I tried giving position: fixed in various divs. But the content goes to left if i do that. Any help?

Comment: Is there a reason you've tagged this with `jquery` `javascript` and `jquery-ui`? Your example code contains none of them. Also, this issue is going to be almost impossible to solve without seeing a working example of the problem, ideally in a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: why have you not tagged  this question.. with html and css ?? cause that's the only things used there..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete what is `<table id="container"...>` with no end tag.
For your code it could be sudden change of height or width of an html component on some event